# Pure JS solution similar to ASP.NET Wizard Steps

Tags: javascript, .net

Coming from the desire to not use a ASP.NET Wizard Step which will require refactoring a ton of markup into ASP controls, I'm wondering if there is a pure JavaScript solution to do something similar to that of a Wizard Step?

Essentially, I want to have one screen then use something like ajax on a button "Next" click to simply update the markup inside of the main content area without the screen flicker I would see if I used the same template on the first page, then link to the second. One bonus would be that the content-to-come isn't visible when you "Inspect Element" or view source in the browser.

And a side question: Outside of ASP.NET land what is this behavior called?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/0rwuynj1) that shows a Wizard implementation using Syncfusion [ejTab](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejtab) JavaScript control.

The content-to-come can be made invisible if we changed the sample to pull in content on demand using AJAX. Please let me know if you are interested in that option.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

I work for Syncfusion.